# How to scrape inner div class using python Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

How to scrape the inner class of  `<div class="_15bab5p1_6101">` under the outer class `<a class="_1yxeg5wb_6101">` .

I want to be able to scrape and download the .jpg file inside the  and also at the same time get the corresponding href in the `<div class="_15bab5p1_6101">` , but it seems when I do it using the code below the href doesn't correspond with the .jpg file.

For example, download: https://secure.img1-cg.wfcdn.com/im/69105935/resize-h160-w160%5Ecompr-r85/1969/196985839/Liebert+52%27%27+Wide+Solid+Wood+Loveseat+with+Knight+Style.jpg , then save the corresponding href: https://www.wayfair.ca/furniture/pdp/kelly-clarkson-home-liebert-52-wide-solid-wood-loveseat-with-knight-style-c007901524.html

```
def get_links_and_images_from_web(url, wd, delay):
    wd.get(url)
    image_urls = []
    links = []
    thumbnails = wd.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "_15bab5p1_6101")
    for img in thumbnails:
        try:
            img.click()
            time.sleep(delay)
        except:
            continue
        images = wd.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'img[data-hb-id="FluidImage"]')
        for image in images:
            if image.get_attribute('src') and 'http' in image.get_attribute('src'):
                image_urls.append(image.get_attribute('src'))
                print(f"Found {len(image_urls)} images:", image_urls[-1])
        elements = img.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "_1yxeg5wb_6101")
        for element in elements:
            ele = element.get_attribute("href")
            links.append(ele)
            print(f"Found {len(links)} links:", ele)
    return links, image_urls

url = "https://www.wayfair.ca/furniture/sb0/sofas-c413892.html?itemsperpage=96"
wd = webdriver.Chrome()

get_links_and_images_from_web(url, wd, 5)
```

link [here](https://www.wayfair.ca/furniture/sb0/sofas-c413892.html?itemsperpage=96) and
html screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTSjA.png)